# Error installing react-native-onesignal on iOS using react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, onesignal

I am having problem setting up OneSignal on iOS, it worked pretty well for android.

In Podfile I added:

```
pod 'react-native-onesignal', 
    :podspec => "../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/react-native-onesignal.podspec",
    :path => '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal'
```

Error:

> Error installing react-native-onesignal [!] /usr/local/bin/git clone
>    git+https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal.git.git
>    /var/folders/hp/96xj1gkj76s_x7hbh3rd2vs80000gn/T/d20180426-27872-elbnyw
>    --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch
>
> fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'git+https'

Any idea what would be wrong in here?

Comment: did you ever get this to work with pods? i can't use it without pods

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this in your terminal to make it work:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git+https://
```